# Get cron to send html-formatted emails

Tags: email, cron

I have a stats program which runs on log files via cron.  The stats program can output HTML.

Right now I rely on the MAIL_TO mechanism in the crontab.

```
MAILTO=my@email.addr
55 23 * * * /usr/bin/htmlstats
```

The problem is that I want the email sent to display as HTML and not as plain text.

Cron places the following header in the email:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
```

Any idea how I would change this to:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. A solution could be to pipe the output to sendmail or mail, which gives you more control over content type and other headers.

Comment: Thanks.  I gave the piping to mail a go and I'm happy with what I'm seeing.  All the best!

Comment: The `CONTENT_TYPE` variable solution mentioned in another answer seems to work at least in some cron versions.

Answer (score 23):

I put the `CONTENT_TYPE="text/plain; charset=utf-8"` in `/etc/crontab` to have my mail in UTF-8.

Put `CONTENT_TYPE="text/html; charset=utf-8"` in `/etc/crontab` to send the mail in HTML.

You may add it in specific file if the directory `/etc/cron.d/` exists. In this case, the specification is defined only for the requested tasks.

Comment: This is awesome... can confirm it works on Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Comment: @billynoah yes, this should be the accepted answer.  Works on archlinux, cronie 1.5.1-1

Comment: worked on centos

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 16

Comment: Doesn't appear to work on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score -1):

YES, you can.

```
<?php exec('(  echo "test<br>créer un mail"| mail -s "SUBJECT" -a "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" '.$receiver.' -- -f '.$sender.' ) &> /dev/null &'); ?>
```