# sending email from cron in html format not text

Tags: php, email, cron, centos6

i am trying to send `email` every 1 hour from `cron` job which is executing a `php` script that fetches data from database and shows in a table format.

i have `CentOs 6.1` where i created my cron job.firstly i installed `cronie` from terminal `yum install cronie`.then i type `crontab -e` and opens VI editor

there i put my cron with a MAILTO like

```
MAILTO="someemail@ex.com"
10 * * * * php /var/www/html/myfile.php
```

its sending email every 1hour past 10min but its sending email in a text content which i dont want.

`myfile.php`

```
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);
$to="some@example.com"
$subject = 'Count User Login And Application';

//fetch between 06:00:00 to 08:30:00   09:00:00 to 10:00:00
$date=array('06:00:00','09:00:00');
$date1=array('08:30:00','10:00:00');

$msg  = '<html><head>';
$msg .='<title>Some Title</title>';
$msg .='</head>';
$msg .='<h1>Test User</h1>';
$msg .='<table border="1" cellspacing="1">';

$msg .=  "<tr>";
$msg .=  "<th>start time</th>";
$msg .=  "<th>end time</th>";
$msg .=  "<th>Count</th>";

$count=count($date);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$sql="SELECT count(*) AS test FROM table_name WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sys_time,'%H:%m:%i') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(sys_time,'$date[$i]') AND  DATE_FORMAT(sys_time,'$date1[$i]') ";
$query=mysql_query($sql);

if(!$query){
die('could not connect'.mysql_error());}


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$msg .=  "<tr>";
$str=$row['test'];
$subcategory = explode(',', $str);
foreach($subcategory as $value) 
{
    $msg .=  "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
 }
$msg .=  "</tr>";
  } 
}
$msg .=  "</table>";      
$msg .=  "</html>";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $msg);
?>
```

as i am using simple `mail()` in php with `headers` to render it in `html` but my `cron` is sending mail in text format and not html format.

i am trying to get email in table format like one get in from browser but i am getting in text format.

is it possible to get email in html format from cron

any other possibilities is always welcomed.i have tried every if's and but's that i can get from google but i cant find a way to work it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the not accepted answers to a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/102235) it depends on which version of cron you're running.

Check `man 5 crontab` if setting the CONTENT_TYPE and/or CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING variables is supported to change from the default plain text.

AFAIK in cronie on RHEL 6 it is and if the output from script is HTML formatted the following should work in your crontab:

```
MAILTO="someemail@example.com"
CONTENT_TYPE="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
10 * * * * php /var/www/html/myfile.php
```

Comment: thank you for response.by typing man 5 crontab from centos terminal i get a cronie user manual.i have append your lines in crontab.lets c ..cheers!

Comment: i am getting this in mail 
`/bin/sh:-c line 0 enexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'/bin/sh:-c line1:syntax error:unexpected EOF`

Comment: Check that your quotes are the correct ' " ' quotes and not two ' ` ' or even ' “ ' and ' ” ' quotes. And make sure that when you execute `php /var/www/html/myfile.php` from the commandline returns HTML and no errors.

Comment: OK just to be clear, the MAILTO in your crontab redirects the STDOUT and STDERR the script generates to your mail recipient. That is a completely different message from the email message sent from the php `mail()` function in the script that gets executed.

Comment: actually i have done a mistake in my script to throw errors like in the top of my script i have placed #!/user/bin/env php which i removed and the error is gone.

and actually putting the headers `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";` in top of my script after $to works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I use mutt to send cron output as HTML

`... <cron command> | mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s "Subject" user@example.com -b admin@example.com`